# Can't invoke injected google maps v3 api throgh JSNI:$wnd.google.maps.LatLng is not a constructor

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3, jsni

I am trying use google maps by JSNI,Following code snippet throws out an exception:

com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): $wnd.google.maps.LatLng is not a constructor at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:248)
.....

### can anybody help me to point out what's wrong here?

```
@Override
public void init(final Point center, final int zl)
{
    ScriptInjector
            .fromUrl(   "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language="
                                + Cookies.getCookie(LocaleInfo.getLocaleCookieName()))
            .setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>()
            {
                public void onFailure(Exception reason)
                {
                    // I18N
                    Window.alert("load google maps api failed,all map function will not work.");
                }

                public void onSuccess(Void result)
                {
                    map = initMap(getElement(), center.getLatitude(), center.getLongitude(), zoomLevel = zl);
                }
            }).inject();
}

native JavaScriptObject initMap(Element canvas, double latitude, double longitude, int zoomLevel) /*-{
    return new $wnd.google.maps.Map(canvas, {
        zoom : zoomLevel,
        center : new $wnd.google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        mapTypeId : $wnd.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
}-*/;
```

Comment: any reason why you don't use on of the GWT Maps V3 wrappers ?

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-maps-v3/ or the newer one http://code.google.com/p/gwt-maps-api/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing the third optional boolean parameter for `noWrap`? Maybe you are running into some bug with DevMode. Have you tried running the same code once the app is deployed?

Comment: Tried your suggestion:add third parameter:noWrap,some problem as before in both Dev and Deployed model

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is that your callback (from your custom script injector) is firing before the script is actually loaded. Can you just include the Google Maps api script in your host page and see if it works this way?

Comment: Including it in host page will work,but what I want to do is decrease initial downloading time,so inject it dynamically.

Comment: @AlexLuya, well then it leads to believe that the GWT ScriptInjector class is not working correctly with the Google Maps JS import.

Answer (score 0):

The MAP API is injecting other JavaScript library, after the first is loaded.

For loading the Map API after the page load Google provides an additional parameter callback. The callback method is call after the API is loaded.

To get it work youo have to register a GWT Method that can be called from a outside javascript block.

```
   public static native void exportStaticMethod() /*-{
    $wnd.mapInit = $entry(@com.my.test.client.MyProject::init());
   }-*/;
```

Excecute this method on you onModuleLoad and it can be excecuted from outside java script like this:

```
function initialize()
{
        window.mapInit();
}
```

What is missing is the injection of the map API in your GWT code:

```
ScriptElement element = Document.get().createScriptElement();
    element.setLang("javascript");
    element.setType("text/javascript");
    element.setSrc("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize&sensor=false");
    Document.get().getElementsByTagName("head").getItem(0).appendChild(element);
```

After the script is load the init method is excuted.

```
private static void init()
{
    System.out.println("loaded");
}
```

See here [Loading Client-side APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/clientside/load)